# Splitting String into words using isLetter() and then print out each word at a new line

Tags: java, string

```
input:
this is a line

output:
this
is
a
line
```

the idea is that the user will enter one line and then it will be printed out one word at one line and then going on. 
buffer and inputString are variables of String.

```
    for (int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(inputString.charAt(i))){
            buffer += i;
        }// end if
    }// end for i
```

to end it all with my cool error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable buffer may not have been initialized
```

I'm quite new to java coding and I know there are many other ways to solve this task like using the split() and some others. But my sadistic teacher want me to use the isLetter() for this one.

Comment: *"Unresolved compilation problem"*   Resolve the compilation problems before trying to run code.  If you cannot solve them, post the relevant code and compilation output.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks, didn't know it's 'deprecated'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable buffer may not have been initialized
```

means that you have declared a variable, (maybe a String?) but not initialized it.

Replace

```
String buffer;
```

with

```
String buffer = "";
```

I'm not sure what your loop does exactly, adding the counter to anything doesn't really make sense to me, but that's another story.

Comment: Somehow that worked. What is the diffrence with String Test; and string Test = "";

Comment: `String buffer` creates a variable that can point to a `String`, but doesn't create a `String`. `String buffer = ""` creates a variable and points it to an empty `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Initialized the variable Buffer with an empty string like this String Buffer = ""; 
or you can use char type to store a character when the specified condition is true and than laterly concatenate these chars into string.